# Summation of prices that can change by Radio Button

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:
HTML

```
<div>
    <p>Whatsit:<span class="price"></span></p>
    <p>Whosit: <span class="whositprice"></span></p>
    <p>Total Price: <span class="totalPrice"></span></p>
</div>
<div>
    <h4>Select a whatsit</h4>
    <input type="radio" name="whatsit" value="whatsit1" />Whatsit 1 - $10
    <input type="radio" name="whatsit" value="whatsit2" />Whatsit 2 - $22
<h4>Select a whosit</h4>
    <input type="radio" name="whosit" value="whosit1" />Whosit 1 - $7
    <input type="radio" name="whosit" value="whosit2" />Whosit 2 - $13
```

jQuery

```
function updateWhatPrice(){
    var whatsitChoice = $("input[name='whatsit']:checked").val();
    if(whatsitChoice == "whatsit1"){
        $("span.price").text("$10");
    }else if(whatsitChoice =="whatsit2"){
        $("span.price").text("$22");
    }
}
$("input[name='whatsit']").click(function(){
    updateWhatPrice();
});
function updateWhoPrice(){
    var whositChoice = $("input[name='whosit']:checked").val();
    if(whositChoice == "whosit1"){
        $("span.whositprice").text("$7");
    }else if(whositChoice =="whosit2"){
        $("span.whositprice").text("$13");
    }
}
$("input[name='whosit']").click(function(){
    updateWhoPrice();
});
```

What I want to do is update the totalPrice span based on the selections of the radio buttons. Not sure where to start. Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Djd3d/

Comment: need help my question is similar here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/q/69347993/16967954

Comment: need answer my question is similar here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/q/69347993/16967954

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following, which requires a minor change to your HTML:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    var self = this,
        price = self.nextSibling.nodeValue.match(/\$(\d+)/)[0];
    $('span.' + this.name + 'price').text(price);
    $('span.totalPrice').text(function(){
        return (parseInt($('span.whatsitprice').text().replace(/\$/,''),10) || 0) + (parseInt($('span.whositprice').text().replace(/\$/,''), 10) || 0);
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Djd3d/4/).

The changed HTML is to make the `span` class-names consistent, following the pattern of the `name` of the radio `input`, plus the `price` string.

---

**Edited** to address the [question raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16799885/summation-of-prices-that-can-change-by-radio-button/16800144?noredirect=1#comment24654271_16800144), in the comments (below), by the OP:

> What do you do if one of the options has a price of $0. E.g. Whatsit 1 comes at no extra cost....but you want to leave it blank and not have $0 there...

In the event of there being no text following the `input`, or no no matched numbers following a `$` character:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    var self = this,
        // caching the text of the nextSibling
        next = self.nextSibling.nodeValue,
        /* checking that there is a string of numbers following a $ character,
           if there is we return that sequence of numbers to the variable,
           if not we set the price to 0, to avoid NaN problems later.
        */
        price = next.match(/\$(\d+)/) ? next.match(/\$(\d+)/)[0] : 0;

    $('span.' + this.name + 'price').text(price);
    $('span.totalPrice').text(function(){
        return (parseInt($('span.whatsitprice').text().replace(/\$/,''),10) || 0) + (parseInt($('span.whositprice').text().replace(/\$/,''), 10) || 0);
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Djd3d/8/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FparseInt).
- [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Fmatch).
- [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2Freplace).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: I'm sure that this is the correct answer, but I am not familiar with .match and the (/\$.... that follows. Is there somewhere that I can learn more about what is happening here?

Comment: There certainly is; I'm sorry, ordinarily I'd have posted the 'references' after posting the answer. In this case I apparently forgot. See added references, they should make things more clear as to what's happening. =)

Comment: What do you do if one of the options has a price of $0. E.g. Whatsit 1 comes at no extra cost....but you want to leave it blank and not have $0 there...

Comment: The error message is pretty explanatory, it would come up only if there is no `nextSibling` of the current node. Has your HTML changed?

Comment: Silly mistake on my part. Thanks for following up. Curious how I could add a base price to the summation...the page would start with Total Price = Base Price: http://jsfiddle.net/Djd3d/21/

Answer (score 1):

You can create another function that returns the total.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Djd3d/1/

I added 0's as placeholders inside your `<spans>` and created the following code:

```
function getTotal() {
    return (parseInt($(".price").text().split("$")[1]) + parseInt($(".whositprice").text().split("$")[1]));
}
```

And added it to your change events:

```
$("input[name='whosit']").click(function(){
    updateWhoPrice();
    $(".totalPrice").text("$" + getTotal());
});

$("input[name='whatsit']").click(function(){
    updateWhatPrice();
    $(".totalPrice").text("$" + getTotal());
});
```