# calculate price depend on selection without button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sum, multiplication

I want to add price and multiply with if statement to clarify here is some price for variable
Private=100 for adults and 50 for children or shared=40 for adults and 30 for children
with atv=100 for adult 80 for children or without atv=0

if the only adult is booking on the web I want the price to react like the sum of both selections multiply with the number of adult example
the adult book shared with ATV so 40+100=140 * number of adult

if adults and children are booking shared with ATV then it should react like
40+100=140 * number of adults
30+80=110 * no of children
the result should be summing (110 * number of children) + (140 * number of adults)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .small-img-group {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    .small-img-col {
      flex-basis: 24%;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .counter1 {
      float: left;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    
    .counter2 {
      float: left;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      padding-left: 15px;
    }
    
    .up,
    .down {
      display: inline-block;
      color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      font-size: 20px;
      margin: 1px 1px;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 15px;
      line-height: 14px;
      height: 16px;
      text-align: center;
      font-weight: bold;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    .up:hover,
    .down:hover {
      color: #fd0b3f;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .adults {
      padding-right: 5px;
    }
    
    .children {
      padding-right: 5px;
    }
    
    input {
      appearance: none;
      height: 21px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 42px;
      line-height: 24px;
      font-size: 15px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .container {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    input[type="radio"] {
      display: none;
    }
    
    label[for=private] {
      position: relative;
      color: orangered;
      font-size: 20px;
      border: 2px solid orangered;
      border-radius: 5px;
      align-items: left;
      display: flex;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    label[for=shared] {
      position: relative;
      color: orangered;
      font-size: 20px;
      border: 2px solid orangered;
      border-radius: 5px;
      align-items: left;
      display: flex;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
      background-color: orangered;
      color: white;
    }
    
    input[type="radio"]:checked+label:before {
      height: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      border: 10px solid white;
      background-color: orangered;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <section class="container sproduct my-5 pt-5">
    <div class="row mt-5">
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 col-12">
        <img class="img-fluid w-100 pb-1" src="https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg" alt="" id="MainImg" width="450">

        <div class="small-img-group">
          <div class="small-img-col">
            <img src="https://media.tacdn.com/media/attractions-splice-spp-674x446/09/99/99/87.jpg" width="100%" class="small-img" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="small-img-col">
            <img src="https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg" width="100%" class="small-img" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="small-img-col">
            <img src="https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg" width="100%" class="small-img" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="small-img-col">
            <img src="https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg" width="100%" class="small-img" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-12">
        <h6>Home / Morning Safari</h6>
        <h3>Morning Safari</h3>
        <h2> <label> Total:</label><label class="total Price"></label> </h2>
        <div class="counter1">
          <Label class="Adults">Adults</Label>
          <div class='down' onclick='decreaseCount(event, this)'>-</div>
          <input type='text' value='1' readonly>
          <div class='up' onclick='increaseCount(event, this)'>+</div>
        </div>
        <div class="counter2">
          <Label class="Children">Children</Label>
          <div class='down' onclick='decreaseCount2(event, this)'>-</div>
          <input type='text' value='0' readonly>
          <div class='up' onclick='increaseCount(event, this)'>+</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="padding-left: 0;padding-top: 5px;">
          <div>
            <input type="radio" name="occupancy" id="private" checked="checked">
            <label for="private">Private</label>
            <input type="radio" name="occupancy" id="shared">
            <label for="shared">Shared</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="radio" name="atv" id="withatv" checked="checked">
            <label for="withatv">With ATV</label>
            <input type="radio" name="atv" id="withoutatv">
            <label for="withoutatv">Without ATV</label>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    function increaseCount(e, el) {
      var input = el.previousElementSibling;
      var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
      value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
      value++;
      input.value = value;
    }

    function decreaseCount(e, el) {
      var input = el.nextElementSibling;
      var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
      if (value > 1) {
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        value--;
        input.value = value;
      }
    }

    function decreaseCount2(e, el) {
      var input = el.nextElementSibling;
      var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
      if (value > 0) {
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        value--;
        input.value = value;
      }
    }

    var MainImg = document.getElementById('MainImg');
    var smallimg = document.getElementsByClassName('small-img');

    smallimg[0].onclick = function() {
      MainImg.src = smallimg[0].src;
    }
    smallimg[1].onclick = function() {
      MainImg.src = smallimg[1].src;
    }
    smallimg[2].onclick = function() {
      MainImg.src = smallimg[2].src;
    }
    smallimg[3].onclick = function() {
      MainImg.src = smallimg[3].src;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did multiple changes to be able to work with this in an easier way:

- **Step 0 - HTML** Include id in `adults`, `children` input (to be able to get those values)
- **Step 1 - HTML** After every modification (change children/adult, atv/no atv, private/shared) render not total
- **Step 2 - JS** Calculate new total and render

The Plnkr with the example: https://plnkr.co/edit/XOebeFyHNXFswNI4

**Step 0 & 1: HTML:**

```html
                onclick="updateTotal()"
              />
              <label for="withatv">With ATV</label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="atv"
                id="withoutatv"
                onclick="updateTotal()"
              />
              <label for="withoutatv">Without ATV</label>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**Step 2:**

```js
      function calculateTotal() {
        // Define based Prices
        const privateAdultPrice = 100;
        const sharedAdultPrice = 40;
        const privateChildrenPrice = 50;
        const sharedChildrenPrice = 30;

        const withAtvAdultPrice = 100;
        const withAtvChildrenPrice = 80;

        const noAtvPrice = 0;

        // Get the amount of adults and guests
        const adults = +document.querySelector('#adults').value;
        const children = +document.querySelector('#children').value;

        // Get the type of trip
        const isPrivate = document.getElementById('private').checked;
        const isWithAtv = document.getElementById('withatv').checked;        

        // Calculate the specific charge per type of user and type of trip
        const adultTripPrice = isPrivate ? privateAdultPrice : sharedAdultPrice;
        const childrenTripPrice = isPrivate ? privateChildrenPrice : sharedChildrenPrice;
        // Calculate the specific charge per type of user and the vehicule\
        const adultVehiclePrice = isWithAtv ? withAtvAdultPrice : noAtvPrice;
        const childrenVehiclePrice = isWithAtv ? withAtvChildrenPrice : noAtvPrice;      

        // Finally, do the maths
        const adultPrice = adults * (adultTripPrice + adultVehiclePrice)
        const childrenPrice = children * (childrenTripPrice + childrenVehiclePrice)

        // return the value
        return adultPrice + childrenPrice;                  
      }

      function updateTotal() {
        const total = calculateTotal();
        console.log(total);
        document.querySelector('#totalPrice').innerHTML = total;
      }
```

Comment: wow so perfect, first of all, I would thank you for doing this, everything seems as I want but the only thing is when you load this page although private is checked you need to click it again to show the total and if you could tell me in future i might edit this to add with sunrise and without sunrise option so how will be my jquery be edited

Comment: Let's define in 2 separet elements: load at beginning will be enough to run `calculateTotal()` at the end of your script. About the sunrise will works as the previous parts, one example here: https://plnkr.co/edit/xenaIzgdG1LP2ham

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer and upvote if it works :) @MMunir.Asif

Comment: thanks buddy so helpful

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69339515/16967954 answer this also pls

Comment: hi i want to know one thing which you did above. i am getting total perfect but when i want to pass this i cant example when we have any input number where we can increment the value we can pass it to checkout session but this value dosent go there it says nulll any solution you got

Comment: i got on new situation can you help me with it, same format but I want like 
if private is selected with atv price should be 100 and without 50

if shared is selected atv price should be 50 and without atv 25 

can you help me in your style like above pls

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71008409/price-depend-on-selection-of-radio-input

you can answer here as you deserve an upvote